# android 2.3 emulator hangs after adb shell stop then start

Tags: android, emulation, adb, logcat

In android 2.2, I was able to start the emulator, then run 'adb shell stop' 'adb shell start' to have the emulator come back up.  Since changing to android 2.3 the emulator will not start, and logcat hangs with these messages:

SettingsProvider   cache for settings table 'secure' rows=27; fullycached=true
qemud              fdhandler_accept_event: accepting on fd 9
qemud              created client 0x11f88 listening on fd 11
qemud              client_fd_receive: attempting registration for service 'hw-control'
qemud              client_fd_receive:    -> received channel id 5
SettingsProvider   cache for settings table 'system' rows=45; fullycached=true

I'm using eclipse, thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

It might be a problem with one of the long running process re-establishing itself with qemu HW simulation. Kill the process `/system/bin/qemud` and then start the emulator.

Steps

1. `adb shell stop`
2. `adb shell ps` (get the pid of `/system/bin/qemud`)
3. `adb kill <pid_process>`
4. `adb shell start`

Comment: This starts the emulator, but then I have no networking.  Any to fix it?